# Maintaining extra data for .laz for use in R and Python?

Tags: las, lidr, laspy

I am working on releasing a benchmark dataset for trees in RGB + Lidar and I'd like the format to match the most common use cases and packages. I had been intending on proving a tree index using the user_data column. Alot of preprocessing happens in python and i'm writing from laspy. I realized that user_data is clamped 0-255 (there are thousands of trees), meaning that trees do not have a unique index. I'm starting to write an extra dimension function

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815580/appending-an-index-to-laspy-file-las

but looking here, it looks like lidR is going to ignore those columns

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAS-class.html

and i'll need users to do lasadddata anyways. Perhaps it would be best to just provide a csv lookup table based on x,y,z? With millions of points, will this be the best strategy? I'm worried about precision rounding among platforms. Thoughts welcome on how future users will best interact with extra dim data.

EDIT: The question was deemed too broad. So here is a literal example.

Here is a python pandas dataframe (taken from a laspy-like object) with the x,y,z coordinates of a point and an associated label. What is the best way to write this label information and load it in the R lidR package.

```
pc.head()
              x            y       z   label
272  315547.689  4094399.467  12.288   562.0
287  315541.905  4094400.774   4.151  2233.0
289  315541.279  4094400.842   4.166  2233.0
291  315541.725  4094400.506   8.189  2233.0
292  315540.776  4094400.865   5.199  2233.0
```

One option is to write to csv and the use lasadddata function add the extra attribute "label" in R separately. However, for a reasonably large point cloud, this would create a 100MB file, which would then be read into R and then joined to ensure the vector order lined up

If you directly write the laspy point cloud, and stick the label data in the user_data column, values above 255 will be clamped by laspy. See link above.

ANSWER:

Because this was flagged, I can't answer my own question. As @JRR noted, the key aspect is to be mindful of the datatype. lidR will read the extra attribute. I hope this helps someone in the future.

So in python

```
import laspy

def write_label(point_cloud, path):

    #Create laspy object
    outFile1 = laspy.file.File(path, mode = "w",header = inFile.header)

    #First define the new types

    outFile1.define_new_dimension(
        name="label",
        data_type=5, #Data types may matter
        description = "Integer Tree Label"
     )

    # copy fields from laspy object
    for dimension in inFile.point_format:
        dat = inFile.reader.get_dimension(dimension.name)
        outFile1.writer.set_dimension(dimension.name, dat)

    outFile1.label = <label column from pandas here>
    outFile1.close()
```

lidR sees a new **integer** column "label"

```
> colnames(a@data)
 [1] "X"                          "Y"                          "Z"                          "gpstime"                   
 [5] "Intensity"                  "ReturnNumber"               "NumberOfReturns"            "ScanDirectionFlag"         
 [9] "EdgeOfFlightline"           "Classification"             "Synthetic_flag"             "Keypoint_flag"             
[13] "Withheld_flag"              "ScanAngle"                  "UserData"                   "PointSourceID"             
[17] "R"                          "G"                          "B"                          "reversible index (lastile)"
[21] "label"
```

Comment: The issue is: you added non standard attributes into a las file with `laspy` but `lidR` does not recognize those extra attributes. Correct? Can you share a reproducible example as well as an example file (with ten points only for example) + give us at least the file format used.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I think the broader question is more important, what is the best way to share non-standard attributes such that future users in lidR and (less extent) laspy will be able to handle them efficiently? Is a x,y,z + index csv file the best idea? For a reasonable sized point cloud, thats over a 100MB file. Trying to get feedback from the community on greatest reproducibility and utility.

Comment: This would be fine to ask in the GIS Chat Room but seeking a list of opinions is too broad for the focused Q&A of the Main site.

Comment: edited to be more literal.

Comment: The best option is to write an extra byte attributes as you did. I just tested to write extra byte attributes with `laspy` following [laspy documentation](https://pythonhosted.org//laspy/tut_part_3.html). Then I read back the new lasfile in R with `rlas` and the extrabyte attributes were read. However with lidR the extrabyte were missing. It is either a bug or related to invalid file written by laspy.

Comment: Erratum. Extrabytes were read with lidR as well. I think your question should be "how to write valid extra byte with laspy". Imo your file is invalid but without reproducible code we can't help you more.

Comment: @JRR you are correct. its the extrabytes that did it. I can change datatypes and it seems to work. Will post code.

Comment: Your question have been unlocked. Could you edit the question to be representative of the actual problem and put your answer in an answer.

Comment: @bw4sz Could you please add your answer in the answer section rather than your question as an edit so we can consider this question resolved?